# Trouble posting file to a server using superagent

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack-dev-server, superagent

This may be a basic question, but I haven't been able to find the solution anywhere so hopefully it will be helpful to others.

I have created a React.js application that I want to use to upload a file to the development server I am running using webpack. When I try to 'post' files to this server (using the react component superagent) I get the following error 'http://localhost:8080/upload Error 404 (Not Found)'.

If I navigate to this address in my browser window I see that the folder exists on the server. Additionally, I the file information is logged to the console so I know my application is receiving this information.

The set up of my project is as follows:

**/app/index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Highcharts Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="dropzone"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**/app/main.js**

```js
var React = require('react');
var Dropzone = require('react-dropzone');
var request = require('superagent');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var PicDropzone = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <Dropzone onDrop={this.dropHandler}>
        < div > Drop a photo, or click to add. < /div >
      </Dropzone>
    );
  },
  dropHandler: function(acceptedFiles) {
    //var photo = new FormData();
    //photo.append('photo', file[0]);
    console.log(acceptedFiles);
    request.post('/upload')
    //.send(photo)
    .end(function(err, resp) {
      if (err) { console.error(err); }
      return resp;
    });
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<PicDropzone />, document.getElementById('dropzone'));
```

**/package.json**

```html
{
  "name": "dropzone",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "multer": "^1.2.1",
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dropzone": "^3.8.0",
    "superagent": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.24.1",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  }
}
```

**/webpack.config.js**

```js
var HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
  template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = {
  entry:[
    __dirname + '/app/main.js'
  ]
  ,
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'transformed.js',
    path: __dirname + '/build'
  },
  plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig]
};
```

In my root folder I also have the upload folder, a folder with the translated jsx, the node modules, and the babel config. Do I need to somehow allow my application to access http://localhost:8080/upload somewhere in the config files? I am guessing I am missing something in the set-up here, but I haven't been able to figure out what that is.